# Discord bot on heroku it's crashing without have an error

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm new here sorry if I'm wrong.. Can someone please help me what is happening with my discord bot in heroku I connect to this site I did all requirements and in heroku view logs my bot is starting but some minutes later it keeps crashing without reason and without error please help :( I read some of old posts but still same.. Thanks!